# написать итерационную функцию на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробовал:

```
def task3(m, n, b, y):
#function = ((1-c**3-j)**5)/13+1+(c**3+23*k**2+y)**6
result = 1
r = 0
for j in range(1, b+1):
    for k in range(1, n+1):
        f = 0
        for c in range(1, m+1):
            f +=(((1-c**3-j)**5)/13)+1+((c**3+23*(k**2)+y)**6)
        result *= f
    result = 0
r = "{:.2e}".format(r)
return r
```

долго над этим сижу - не понимаю алгоритм, было бы круто ответ с объяснением. спасибо заранее :3

Comment: Слишком много скобок, можно легко запутаться, вот так сделайте: `(1 - c**3 - j)**5/13 + 1 + (c**3 + 23*k**2 + y)**6`. И result (будущий результат произведения) нужно не обнулять, а присваивать 1. Лучше просто `result = 1` внутрь первого for внести, а `result = 0` удалить. P.S. и результат произведения забыли прибавить к r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну почти правильно:

```
def task3(m, n, b, y):
#function = ((1-c**3-j)**5)/13+1+(c**3+23*k**2+y)**6
    result = 0
    for j in range(1, b+1):
        prod = 1
        for k in range(1, n+1):
            f = 0
            for c in range(1, m+1):
                f +=(((1-c**3-j)**5)/13)+1+((c**3+23*(k**2)+y)**6)
            prod *= f
        result += prod
    return result
```